# Converting Chrome Extension to Edge Extension, Permissions issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I have a chrome extension I have made and I want to convert it to Edge using the Microsoft Edge Extension Converter, everything works fine except for the popups tabs and cookies permissions

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://www.website.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
            "startup.js",
        ],
        "css": [
            "font-awesome.css"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "permissions": [
            "cookies",
            "tabs"
        ]
    }
],
```

If i were to remove

```
"permissions": [
            "cookies",
            "tabs"
        ]
```

The extension will load however the communication between the popup and the window will not work, but if i leave the code in i get the following error

`Manifest parsing error: Invalid field 'permissions' found in 'content_scripts'`.

Answer (score 0):

I try to check the documentation and find that permissions are not the part of content_scripts.

In your sample above, I can see that you are using permissions under content_scripts.

I think this is the cause for this issue.

As per the documentation, following keys can be used with content_scripts.

all_frames, css, exclude_globs, exclude_matches, include_globs, js, match_about_blank, matches, run_at

to get the example refer link below.

[content_scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts)

To solve the issue, you can try to put 'permissions' outside the 'content_scripts'.

Reference:

[permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions)